# Installing w3af in Debian 9 "Strech"?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, debian, debian-stretch

i'm performing security audits for business, i wanted to install w3af on a debian virtualized machine hosted in azure.

#### Platform informations :

Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u6 (2018-10-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux
Debian version : 9.5 ("Strech")

#### w3af_dependency_install.sh's content :

`sudo pip install lxml==3.4.4 scapy-real==2.2.0-dev guess-language==0.2 cluster==1.1.1b3 msgpack==0.5.6 python-ntlm==1.0.1 halberd==0.2.4 darts.util.lru==0.5 Jinja2==2.10 vulndb==0.1.0 markdown==2.6.1 psutil==2.2.1 ds-store==1.1.2 termcolor==1.1.0 mitmproxy==0.13 ruamel.ordereddict==0.4.8 Flask==0.10.1 PyYAML==3.12 tldextract==1.7.2 pebble==4.3.8 acora==2.1 esmre==0.3.1 diff-match-patch==20121119 bravado-core==5.0.2 lz4==1.1.0 vulners==1.3.0`

#### Pip Freeze's output :

`asn1crypto==0.24.0 beautifulsoup4==4.5.3 cffi==1.11.5 chardet==3.0.4 cryptography==2.3.1 enum34==1.1.6 futures==3.2.0 gitdb2==2.0.4 GitPython==2.1.3 html5lib==0.999999999 idna==2.2 ipaddress==1.0.17 keyring==10.1 keyrings.alt==1.3 lxml==3.7.1 ndg-httpsclient==0.4.0 nltk==3.0.1 pdfminer==20140328 phply==0.9.1 ply==3.11 pyasn1==0.4.2 pybloomfiltermmap==0.3.14 pyClamd==0.4.0 pycparser==2.19 pycrypto==2.6.1 PyGithub==1.21.0 pygobject==3.22.0 pyOpenSSL==18.0.0 pyxdg==0.25 SecretStorage==2.3.1 six==1.10.0 smmap2==2.0.4 tblib==0.2.0 webencodings==0.5`

#### Python --version :

2.7.13

#### Errors :

- `Failed building wheel for lxml Running setup.py clean for lxml Failed to build lxml`
- `Can't rollback lxml, nothing uninstalled. Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-fMp2m9/lxml/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-TZ6zpj-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-fMp2m9/lxml/`

Comment: See my related github issue : https://github.com/andresriancho/w3af/issues/17321

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone need an answer on this, I finally managed to install cleanly w3af by installing the lxml dependency myself throught the instructions that i've found on this link [lxml installing instruction](https://lxml.de/installation.html) at the linux section.